# How to Pass values to MVC Models

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

I am currently using MVC and my attempt is to pass a date picker to a Controller. To do this, I have to set my model as per below:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.aDate, new { @type="date"})
```

The above code works fine. However I need to use the below html tag and with a javascript to display the pickup list on click instead:

```
<input type="text" id="datepicker-From" class="form-control">
```

My question is - is there a way to pass models to the html tag above?

Answer (score 1):

You could simply pass the `id` and `class` to the `@Html.TextBoxFor` like this

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.aDate, new { @type="date", @id="datepicker-From", @class="form-control"})
```

Then you could write a script to target the element on the page load

```
window.document.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("datepicker-From").addEventListener("click", function(){
      //Do your stuff here
    });
}
```